# Searching dates in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a date field stored in BigQuery. I would like to search on matching the month or year or entire date. What would be the most performant way to do the following?

```
# An example date looks like "2014-01-01"

# By year
SELECT * FROM index WHERE date LIKE '2014-%'

# By month
SELECT * FROM index WHERE date LIKE '%-01-%'

# By day
SELECT * FROM index WHERE date LIKE '%-\d\d-01'

# By year and month
SELECT * FROM index WHERE date LIKE '2014-01-%'
```

How would I do the above searches in the most performant way in BigQuery?

Note, the above field is of type `DATE`.

Comment: None.  Use the proper date functions, not string functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff would that be much faster than the string matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for BigQuery Standard SQL and assumes that date field stored as DATE type

By year

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM index WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) = 2014
```

By month

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM index WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt) = 1
```

By day

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM index WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM dt) = 1
```

Comment: would you be able to do a quick benchmark comparison of doing a string match vs doing the extract match on a date field to show the difference in perofrmance?